# Load table view on application start

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

I would like my application to remember which selected row in the database table was
used (selected) before the application got closed and then load it (have it selected) the next time the
application starts.The table has only 4 records and is read only so I dont have to worry if someone
tries to change anything.
Right now I use :

```
procedure TForm3.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  Clientdataset1.DisableControls;
  try
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.KeyFieldNames := 'ID';
    cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.LocateByKey('4');
  finally
    Clientdataset1.EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

But this is hardcoded. I want it flexible.
How can I save these settings to an ini file located in the application.exe folder
and load them when the application starts ? So ,for example,if key was '3'
(when the app. exited) I load it the next time.

Comment: If you load the value in `TDataset.OnAfterOpen` then you should save the value in `TDataset.OnBeforeClose` ;o)

Comment: First separate your data out of the form. Use DataModule. On the datamodule you have an Oncreate and an onDestroy. On these event you can use the TRegistryIniFile to store and save the params.

Comment: I dont want to use registry.

Comment: I'd say what @Sir Rufo suggests is the right way. Saving and loading from an INI file is so trivial that doesn't need to be addressed here I think.

Comment: Place ini file into %AppData% path. However using registry is simpler: you would not think where to place the file, so it would not end in read-only folder

Comment: TLama, I have never used ini files before. But, it's no problem....plenty of examples around. What I dont know is how to save the grid view to ini and back.

Comment: @user763539 you don't need to save grid view, you sould save selected row `ID` (primary key)

Comment: It seems theres an eror here ; ....AsString ), [] ); The comma is giving an error....

Comment: Placing the Application INI in the same directory of your application.exe is asking for troubles! I suggest you take the time and learn about UAC...

Comment: @Ravaut123, datamodule.OnCreate is not the right event to do this. it does not guaranty that the DataSet is already opened. I would also use a Flag (e.g. DataSet.Tag) with the `DataSet1AfterOpen` to indicate that it is the first time it's opened because it could be opened/closed several time during the application life-time.

Comment: ini files are simple. More trouble with registry (uac).

Comment: @kobik that is not about UAC at all, that is about normal setup of Windows NT/2000/XP/Vista... - Any Windows except 95/98/ME and higher than reduced Home/Starter editions. `Program Files` are not to be written by non-admin users. Actually UAC makes it easier, as it comes along with FS virtualization in Vista+

Comment: "More trouble with registry (uac)" what ? in which place of registry did you tried to save it ? in protected system-only ? put the values in HKCU/Software/YourName/YourProgramName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TDataSet.OnAfterOpen` and `TDataSet.OnBeforeClose` events to load and save the desired values

```
procedure TForm3.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  LIni : TIniFile;
begin
  DataSet.DisableControls;
  try
    LIni := TIniFile.Create( '<YourIniFileName.ini>' );
    try
      DataSet.Locate( 'ID', LIni.ReadString( 'MyDataSet', 'ID', '' ), [] );
    finally
      LIni.Free;
    end;
  finally
    DataSet.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ClientDataSet1BeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
var
  LIni : TIniFile;
begin
  LIni := TIniFile.Create( '<YourIniFileName.ini>' );
  try
    LIni.WriteString( 'MyDataSet', 'ID', DataSet.FieldByName( 'ID' ).AsString ) );
  finally
    LIni.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This is a very **simple** and **straight forward** sample and you should not implement this in real applications.

In real applications you will delegate this to a singleton that takes care of reading and writing such application values

```
// Very simple KeyValue-Store
IKeyValueStore = interface
  function GetValue( const Key : string; const Default : string ) : string;
  procedure SetValue( const Key : string; const Value : string );
end;

// Global Application Value Store as Singleton   
function AppGlobalStore : IKeyValueStore;
```

and gives you a very smart solution

```
procedure TForm3.ClientDataSet1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.DisableControls;
  try
    DataSet.Locate( 'ID', AppGlobalStore.GetValue( 'MyDataSet\ID', '' ), [] );
  finally
    DataSet.EnableControls;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ClientDataSet1BeforeClose(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  AppGlobalStore.SetValue( 'MyDataSet\ID', DataSet.FieldByName( 'ID' ).AsString ), [] );
end;
```

Comment: @kobik i did those singletons as class properties without creating an actual object :-)

Comment: @Sir Rufo - cant compile your "LIni.WriteString( 'MyDataSet', 'ID', DataSet.FieldByName( 'ID' ).AsString ), [] );" Delphi compiler does not digest the last comma....